# Triple foreign key BelongsToMany Relations returns null in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am implementing pivot table with multiple foreign keys Laravel 5 Eloquent. 
Already read these links

- [How to query pivot table with multiple foreign keys Laravel 5 Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543221/how-to-query-pivot-table-with-multiple-foreign-keys-laravel-5-eloquent)
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/joining-3-tables
- http://laravel.io/forum/04-08-2014-define-relationships-of-a-pivot-table-with-more-than-2-foreign-keys.

My tables are as below:-

```
Quizzes
-Id
-Name

Sections
-Id
-Name

Quiz_Section
-Section_id
-Quiz_Id
-Max_Marks
-Max_Questions

Questions
-Id
-Description

Quiz_Section_Question
-Quiz_id
-Section_Id
-Question_Id
```

Modal-

**Quiz Modal**

```
public function sections()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Section', 'quiz_section', 'quiz_id', 'section_id')->withPivot('max_questions','max_marks');
}

public function sectionsWithName()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\QuizSection','quiz_id', 'id')
    ->join('sections', 'quiz_section.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')
    ->selectRaw('quiz_id, section_id, sections.name, max_questions, max_marks');
}
```

**Section Modal**

```
public function quizzes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Quiz', 'quiz_section', 'section_id', 'quiz_id')->withPivot('max_questions','max_marks');
}

public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question','quiz_section_question', 'section_id','question_id')->withPivot('quiz_id');
}
```

**QuizSection Modal**

```
protected $table = 'quiz_section';


public function Quiz()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Quiz');
}

public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question','quiz_section_question', 'section_id','question_id')->withPivot('quiz_id');
}
```

Now I want to get all sections with name and questions attached to those sections for a particular quiz.

**SQL Query that will give desired output-**

```
SELECT quizzes.name, sections.name, quiz_section.max_marks, quiz_section.max_questions,questions.description FROM quizzes 
INNER JOIN quiz_section ON quizzes.id = quiz_section.quiz_id
INNER JOIN sections ON sections.id = quiz_section.section_id
INNER JOIN quiz_section_question ON (quiz_section_question.quiz_id = quizzes.id AND quiz_section_question.section_id=sections.id)
INNER JOIN questions ON questions .id = quiz_section_question.question_id;
```

I want to do it with Eloquent and Relationships. **I have tried below code:-**

```
 $quiz = \App\Quiz::with('sectionsWithName.questions')->where('name','practice paper')->first();
 dd($quiz->sectionsWithName[0]->questions()->toSql());
```

**Output:-**
Every thing is fine but Questions collection is null.

```
"select * from `questions` inner join `quiz_section_question` on `questions`.`id` = `quiz_section_question`.`question_id` where `quiz_section_question`.`section_id` is null"
```

Please give valuable suggestions.

**Edit:-**
"Section.Questions" relationship returns all questions.

```
 $quiz = \App\Quiz::with('sections.questions')->where('name','practice paper')->first();
 dd($quiz->sections[0]->questions()->toSql());
```

But I want to filter question on basis of Quiz & Sections both.

Comment: I have also run into this problem, did you find a solution?